# Meteor sendVerificationEmail

Tags: angularjs, meteor, email-verification

I'm currently working on revising the registration procedure of our recruitment ATS, made with AngularJS and Meteor, and I need to verify the new user's email during the registration procedure.

The logic would go as followed:

1- User fills in a form on the 'get-started' page and when clicking on 'sumbit', the ATS sends a verification email(I'll be using 'sendVerificationEmail' from Meteor)

2- After the user clicks on the link from the email, they'll get redirected to the 'register' page where additional information is required and the registration procedure is concluded.

As mentioned above, I'm planning to use 'sendVerificationEmail' to verify the user but I also want to use it to send back the userID.

From what I read on the Meteor API, I can pass extra data to the token with 'extraTokenData'

`Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId, [email], [extraTokenData])`

Now how do I declare the 'extraTokenData' object?

Could I do it like this: `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId, "", { _id: userId })`

And how do I retrieve the 'userId' with 'Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink'?

your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you place on using `userId` if the he's not registered yet?!

Comment: well in 1st point, im going to use 'Accounts.createUser()' to create the new user, store any user inputted data and then call 'sendVerificationMail()'.
I'm quite new to AngularJS and Meteor.

Comment: I can definitly how this can go. Here's a link that might help out: https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/adding-a-beta-invitation-system-to-your-meteor-application

Answer (score 0):

The email and the extra tokens are optionals, but if you want to send them send it as a string.
If you want to send the extra token but no emails you can try using `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId, undefined, "extra token")` or if it doesn't work you can request the user's deatil user `Meteor.user()`. then call `user.emails[0].address`.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve information you have to get user by token and all data are there on user document under `services.password.reset` field. Look here how Accounts.generateResetToken is implemented https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/1e7e56eec8414093cd0c1c70750b894069fc972a/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L609.